# Type casting vs pointer casting

Tags: c

Its known that type casting is of the following form

```
(int)x
```

---

What does this mean?

```
(int *) x
```

---

If f is a function , then what does this mean?

```
(void *) f
```

Comment: If x is of type char or bool or so, then you can safely cast it to int. If x is a pointer ot char or so, then you can cast it to a pointer of in. The function f returns a pointer of any type (void).

Comment: @HermannKlecker I've never seen a function return type parenthesized. I would imagine the only way that would ever be seen is if the coder, for some inane reason, wanted to cast the return of f() to a void pointer. I can't imagine why someone would do that, though.

Comment: Yea, it coud be helpful seeing a bit more code for the third part of the question. Could be the address of a function block though. Depends on the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(int *) x` means, take value of `x`, and use it as memory address, which points to a memory location containing an integer. When doing that, programmer should be very careful that value of `x` (whatever type it is) *really does* contain valid address. Otherwise just doing the cast is Undefined Behaviour (though probably does not do anything funny, at least on a PC), and dereferncing=using the pointer will most likely crash with segmentaion fault (because address is not valid memory location).

`(void *)f` casts `f` to "void pointer". It doesn't matter if `f` is function here, because void pointer is kind of special case, used when the code does not actually need to dereference the pointer, it is just passing it through. It means, "here's an address of something". It is used for example with callbacks, when the code setting the callback, and callback function itself do know the type, but the code in between does not.

If you are asking, how a function can be cast to pointer like that, then it's because in C, function name without `()` means pointer to that function. Doing `(void*)f` is not common at all, but there's nothing wrong with if you have a use case where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

`int * p = (int *) x;` means that p is now set to the value of x after x was typecast to an int pointer, same as `int y = (int) x;`.

That void pointer thing...that's not a function pointer declaration. I think you're confusing void pointers and function pointers, neither of which you should be worried about until you understand basic pointers.

Comment: Can you please provide for me a best online tutorial link

Comment: @gm_gm; http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/krnotes/top.html

Comment: If x is the same x in both of your exaples, then it cannot be right.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I'm not assuming it is, and I'm aware it's improper to put them together in the same scope, but he's familiar with the basic typecast (second example), so it makes it easier to understand the pointer typecast (first example).

Comment: Allright. Just trying to avoid misunderstandings.